Reack hook form + nested useFieldArray ON mui datagrid + getDetailPanel
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/whmmy4
steps to reproduce in the above code sandbox

click on plus icon of grid row (expand grid row)
click on the insert button "insert country + 1"
check the error in te console

I have a form which contains Array
and each continents have Array
i have rendered the react hook form with a table displaying the continetns and added a button to insert countries.
But when clicked on button to insert, an error is thrown which i am not able to find a fix.
I have gone though all the contents on google but did not find any solution
i have created a reproducible code sandbox.
Thanks in advance
Expecting to be able to add countries via useFieldArray but it throws error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]'

did you manage to resolve it?
